# I cant push changes on my vscode to my repository on github

Tags: git, github, permissions, repository, git-push

I'm new to Github and recently made a repository. After cloning it on Visual Studios, I created an HTML file but encountered an error when trying to push it to my repository. The error message stated that I didn't have the necessary permissions to push to my repository, and suggested creating a fork instead. I clicked on "create fork" but encountered the same error message when attempting to push to the fork. Can anyone offer assistance?

I have logged out of my Vscode and logged back in, but its still the same, I have also checked if I have git installed, which I do too.

Comment: When you got the same message attempting to push to the fork: had you changed anything about your local copy? If so, what specifically did you do?

Comment: I am guessing that you have cloned the https url instead of the ssh url (e.g `https://github.com/example_user/example_repo` instead of `git@github.com:example_user/example_repo.git`). What does `git remote -v` display?